# How can I display current memory (channel) contents on Beofeng BF-H6?

Tags: baofeng, ht

I cant program it with chirp - but that's a whole other story. I *think* I have programmed it manually, not withstanding hard factual errors in the supplied manual. But now I want to confirm I have entered the tx, rx and ctcss stuff correctly. Anyone know how I can display contents of a memory (also called channel, if I have understood correctly)

Answer (score 1):

[According to this thread](https://forums.radioreference.com/threads/bf-f8hp-editing-channels-on-the-fly.364135/), there isn't a "copy memory to VFO" function so that you can check it all out.

Seems like the best you can do is to get everything *just so* in the VFO and then write (or re-write) to memory.